# Network flooded with LLC packet

Tags: networking, tcp, flooding

Recently my network has been slow. From Tcpdump i found lot of frame with protocol LLC. A complete packet capture can been here [tcpdump result](https://www.cloudshark.org/captures/dfa7559c20c7)

Any hints on interpreting these packet?

Comment: I think you're barking up the wrong tree. The LLC traffic accounts for only 5% of the total traffic in the capture that you've shown. ARP accounts for 29% of the traffic in the capture. Neither says anything about whether or not they're causing network congestion and therefore causing your network slowdown without having more information. Why don't you give us more details on the problem and what you've done to troubleshoot it.

Comment: filtering LLC packet shown 297 out of 412 sample packet. The slowdown happened only in wireless connection. While cabling connection just fine. Scanning traffic on cabling connection doesnot have any LLC proto (maybe 1 or 2 packet)